# Conceal/replace (with astric '*') some characters in a string in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to conceal/replace (with asterisk `*`) some characters in a string in pl/sql like, in some sites in forgot password option they display email IDs or phone numbers like:

```
p******bh****@y****.**.in
```

or

```
+91 9**** **160
```

I want to display first and last characters of every word separated by either `"_" or "." or "@"`.
 All others characters should be displayed as asterix `"*"`.

Any help on this issue?

Comment: Plz elaborate on what criteria you want to show asterix "*"

Comment: OK, I want to display first and last characters of every word separated by either "_" or "." or "@". All others characters should be displayed as asterix "*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write, compile and use something like this function, which may need some adjustments, according to your needs:

```
create or replace function stars(i_str in varchar2) return varchar2 is
  type     chars is table of char(1);
  v_show   chars := chars('@', ' ', '.', '+', '_');
  v_output varchar2(100) := '';
begin
  for i in 1 .. length(i_str) loop
    if i = 1 or i = length(i_str) 
      or substr(i_str, i - 1, 1) member of v_show 
      or substr(i_str, i + 1, 1) member of v_show 
      or substr(i_str, i, 1) member of v_show 
    then
      v_output := v_output || substr(i_str, i, 1);
    else
      v_output := v_output || '*';
    end if;
  end loop;
  return v_output;
end;
```

Test:

```
with test as (
  select 'pabcdefb_habch@yabcy.abc.in' as str from dual union all
  select '+91 91238 51230' from dual union all
  select 'PBhagat'         from dual union all
  select 'Stack Overflow'  from dual)
select str, stars(str) as output from test

STR                          OUTPUT
---------------------------  ---------------------------
pabcdefb_habch@yabcy.abc.in  p******b_h***h@y***y.a*c.in
+91 91238 51230              +91 9***8 5***0
PBhagat                      P*****t
Stack Overflow               S***k O******w
```